# .show() function won't work, even thought it calls the right class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just can't wrap my head around this simple JS. Basically I have a "display: none;" code for my product images, on my product page. But I also have a script which should show specific images with specific image ID of product image. The code finds it without a problem, it however won't add the "show" to it. Any suggestions?

```
    var imagePositions = $('#Variant-Positions option[value="'+current_variant_id+'"]').data("image-positions"); 
    var imagePositionsArr = imagePositions.split(','); 
    
    $.each(imagePositionsArr, function(index, position) { 
      var image = $('.css-yu6q0u [data-image-position="'+position+'"]').show();
      console.log(image);
    });
```

console.log(image) selects the correct class, which is:

```
n.fn.init [prevObject: n.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: '.css-yu6q0u [data-image-position="2"]']
n.fn.init [prevObject: n.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: '.css-yu6q0u [data-image-position="4"]']
```

But it just won't change display none to show.

I tried bunch of other things like "style.display="block"; and "css('display'​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​,'block');​​​​​​". None of it worked either.

I really don't get it.

Would appreciate some pointers.

Comment: Did you inspect the element and look at the CSS and figure out exactly what properties are set on it? Maybe it is a wrapper.... Hard for us to guess what is going on in your HTML/CSS

Comment: The `shopify` tag has nothing to do with this post.

Comment: You need to show your html too if you want to get any help - it is impossible to know what the issue is from the details you have provided.  Please edit your question and use the snippet button to create a [mcve].

Comment: I fixed it by using an "id" now, instead of the "data". That seemed to do the job, guess some kind of workaround. Thanks for trying to help guys.